# Can't find where my meta title for the homepage is pulling from - Magento 2.3.6

Tags: magento2.3, home-page, meta-title

So I'll start by saying I'm not a coder, I just work on the 'front end' in Magento 2. I've updated all our sites meta details for products, categories and content pages, but I can't find where to update the homepage.

I checked the content page that was set as the CMS homepage in **Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Default Pages -> CMS Home Page**. Went to that page in **Content -> Pages**, and the metas in there were blank and not showing what is currently displaying (it's clearly been entered somewhere as it isn't text from our hompage). I did enter the new info here just in case but it didn't work.

I also checked in **configuration > design > HTML Head** to make sure it wasn't a default, but it's not there either.

Is there anywhere else this information could be stored? I don't know how to access or run any code so if that is what needs doing I can ask our techs, but it seems like it should be something I should be able to update!

Answer (score 0):

Open your Magento admin panel and go to:

Content > Pages > Find your home page

See the screenshot below: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vwX4.png

(If you can't find which CMS Page your homepage is set as, you can confirm this by going to Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Default Pages -> CMS Home Page, which will show you which page is being used)

Add your meta title and flush the Magento cache (run the php bin/magento c:f command in CLI)

Finally go onto the front-end of your website and check the changes. (See screenshot): https://i.stack.imgur.com/cphKX.png

Comment: I already tried this and unfortunatly is didn't work - I have my metas in that location but they are not pulling through to the site.

Comment: If it doesn't show any error messages on the screen then this is just a warning of a problem on your site. It won't cause any fatal errors